# Apache Logger Failing in Eclipse Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Currently I'm trying to debug my java file. Tomcat is starting much slower than it usually does (7000ms now  vs < 2000 a while ago), and now the debug fails.

Error Log:

```
2015-01-27 13:00:38,834 ERROR Unable to create file data_reports.txt java.io.IOException: Access is denied.
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:958)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:306)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:290)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:184)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(XLoggerFactory.java:52)
        at org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(XLoggerFactory.java:63)
        at com.ibm.sc.forecast.optimizer.displaygraph.OutputJSONGraph.<clinit>(OutputJSONGraph.java:33)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:612)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

2015-01-27 13:00:38,883 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(XLoggerFactory.java:52)
        at org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(XLoggerFactory.java:63)
        at com.ibm.sc.forecast.optimizer.displaygraph.OutputJSONGraph.<clinit>(OutputJSONGraph.java:33)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:612)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a manager
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:184)
        ... 46 more

2015-01-27 13:00:38,938 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2015-01-27 13:00:38,941 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2015-01-27 13:00:39,142 ERROR Unable to locate appender RollingFile for logger
2015-01-27 13:00:39,145 ERROR Unable to locate appender RollingBadDataFile for logger
```

It appears from the log that tomcat does not have permissions to write to it's own log folder. I have gone into the folder and tried to move the read only part of the folder.

I've also tried disabling TomCats logging, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file path is it trying to create?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it' and where would I check? Thanks for the quick response BTW!